# Laravel Invalid Vendor Folder

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Entré a trabajar en un proyecto y tenia algunos controladores encriptados y me di a la tarea de reescribirlos todos desencriptando el hexa y siguiendo los gotos pero entonces me di cuenta que tambien estaba encriptada la carpeta "Vendor" entonces elimine la carpeta y Ejecute Composer Update, el actualiza bien pero cuando ejecuto algun comando PHP ARTISAN de error "Invalid Vendor Folder"

COMPOSER.JSON

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "greggilbert/recaptcha": "^2.2",
        "laravel/cashier": "7.2.*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "maximebf/debugbar": "^1.15"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
          "app/Http/Helpers.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "repositories": {
        "hooks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://larapack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Vale, ya agregue el composer.json